# Microsoft Visual Studio Code C/C++ Problem

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

i have trouble with vsc.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{ 
    int a;
    printf("Hello World ");
    scanf("%d", &a)
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code. & This is Debug Console.

```
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="args",value="2>CON 1>CON <CON"
[New Thread 13300.0x59d4]
[New Thread 13300.0x367c]
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded
```

When i try to run, it does not start.
I already installed coderunner.
Please help thx.

Comment: Please note that there's no such language like "C/C++". Only the two *very* different and distinct languages C and C++. Please pick *one* of them, the one you're actually writing your code in.

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf` to see how many variables were successfully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by *running it*? Your code looks ok, so I'm guessing you are just doing something wrong when you try to run it.

Firstly, you need to compile your code, and then you can run the program that is created after compilation.

The simplest way to compile both c and c++ is to use console and `gcc`. Try entering this command in the terminal:

```
gcc -Wall -fsanitize=address,undefined -o yourprogram yourprogram.c
```

This should create `yourprogram` file in the directory you are in. To run it, pass this command in the console:

```
./yourprogram
```